# Why this error 65 appears in dependencies in pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter

tell me please why this error appears while i'm trying to install scoped_model:

Running "flutter pub get" in scoped_model...
Error on line 37, column 3 of pubspec.yaml: A package may not list itself as a dependency.
╷
37 │   scoped_model: ^1.1.0
│   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
pub get failed (65;    ╵)
exit code 65

[image]

Comment: Can you please paste the entire `pubspec.yaml` ?

Comment: https://github.com/nikitasalnikov/scoped_model

Comment: you can see this file in github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred because the package name is set to `scoped_model` and again trying to add `scoped_model` at line no. 37, change the name of the package at line number 1.